# JavaScript Preguntas multiples

Tags: javascript, html5

He estado buscando la forma de hacer con JavaScript y HTML preguntas múltiples.

Supongamos que tenemos 3 formularios cada uno con su link:

- "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta1" Donde tiene adentro 10 preguntas
- "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta2" Donde tiene adentro 10 preguntas
- "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta3" Donde tiene adentro 10 preguntas

Ahora el usuario solo vera un botón "Resolver Formulario", ahora se viene la parte difícil por lo menos para mi,

- las primera 10 personas que le den click en el botón "Resolver Formulario" podrán acceder a "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta1"
- las segundas 10 personas que le den click en el botón "Resolver Formulario" podrán acceder a "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta2"
- las terceras 10 personas que le den click en el botón "Resolver Formulario" podrán acceder a "www.linkprueba.com/pregunta3"

Problemas con los que me topé:

1. es que el contador de click se reinicia cada vez que se apreta F5 y no es como un contador global, es decir no funciona con las primeras personas
2. lo mismo pasa que el usuario al darle click al boton varias veces el contador no sume mas puntos es decir 1 punto por persona

luego de explicar el problema ¿hay alguna forma de hacer los puntos 1 y 2 con JavaScript? además de esto como se podría reiniciar el contador una ves llega al 30 pasar a 0 nuevamente

Codigo de boton local:

```
<button id="botonClick">Click</button>
<p id="areaContador"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var botonElement = document.getElementById("botonClick");
    var pElement = document.getElementById("areaContador");
    var contador = 0;
    botonElement.onclick = function() {
        contador++;
        pElement.textContent = contador;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Para hacer un contador global, tendrías que establecer una conexión del lado del servidor usando [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) y una base de datos MySQL, pues JS es un lenguaje del lado del cliente y no podría hacer como tal un contador global, pues se ejecuta a nivel del usuario y no a nivel de todos los usuarios como lo haría un lenguaje del lado del servidor.

Comment: Deberias leer sobre que cosas se pueden hacer en un cliente (y cada uno que se conecta es un cliente diferente) y cuales cosas debes hacer en el servidor. No es necesario que tu base sea MySQL (puede ser cualquiera que te sirva).

Comment: muchas gracias.